# Difference between jQuery find and jQuery with two arguments

Tags: jquery

I have been using jQuery for over a decade, but still have questions about it. What is the difference between:

```
$(element).find(selector)
```

and

```
$(selector, element)
```

?

It seems that both accomplish the same thing and return the same jQuery. Are they implemented differently?

Comment: I would imagine that `$(selector, element)` is a shortcut to `$(element).find(selector)` with one important difference - using `$(element).find(selector)` allows you to use a variable to prefind `$(element)` without having to search the DOM again. That being said you can always do `$(selector, $(element))` too. They are just different ways of doing the same thing.

Comment: From the jquery.js: `if ( !context || context.jquery ) { return ( context.find( selector );` - so `$(selector, element)` is syntax for `$(context).find(selector)`

Comment: "Are they implemented differently?"  - why not inspect the source code?

Answer (score -2):

jQuery find method:

The find method is used to search for descendant elements that match a specified selector within the set of matched elements.
It is typically called on a jQuery object that represents a set of elements.
The syntax is `$(selector).find(subselector)` where `selector` is the initial set of elements, and `subselector` is the selector for the descendant elements.

Example:

```
// Find all <span> elements that are descendants of elements with class "container"
$(".container").find("span");
```

jQuery with two arguments:

When you use two arguments with the jQuery function (e.g., `$(selector, context)`), you are creating a new jQuery object with elements matching the first argument (`selector`) that are descendants of the context specified in the second argument.

The second argument (`context`) is optional and specifies the context in which to search for the elements. If not provided, the search is performed within the entire document.

Example:

```
// Find all <span> elements that are descendants of elements with class "container"
$("span", ".container");
```

In this example, `$("span", ".container")` is equivalent to `$(".container").find("span")`. It selects all `<span>` elements that are descendants of elements with the class "`container`."

In summary, while both methods can be used to select descendant elements, the find method is a specific method designed for this purpose, while using two arguments with the jQuery function is a more general approach that achieves the same result. The choice between them depends on your coding style and preference.

The find method is often preferred when you already have a jQuery object and want to find descendants within it, while using two arguments can be useful when you want to perform a similar search within a specific context.

Comment: Did you create this answer with [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)?

Comment: This doesn't even try to answer the question "are they implemented differently"